# localdate json binding with yasson implementation in wildfly server

Tags: json, wildfly, localdate, jsonb-api, yasson

If I use LocalDate type in my entity class I get the following error if I send a POST request:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor&#x2F;factory method to deserialize from String value (&#x27;1977-01-01&#x27;)
 at [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1, column: 533]
```

If I change my attribute type from

```
@JsonbDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
private java.time.LocalDate mydate;
```

to

```
@JsonbDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
private java.util.Date mydate;
```

it works!

I have tested with Wildfly 15 and 16 (Eclipse Yasson implementation) and the new Java date classes doesn't seem to work with JSON-Bindings.

Is this not supported or do I something wrong?

Comment: How are you attempting to parse the object? The exception is from Jackson, but you mention Yasson. I used the `JsonbBuilder` and it worked for me.

Comment: I annotated my method like this: `@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) public Response add(@Valid Customer newCustomer, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) { ... }`. Shouldn' it automatically be parsed by the framework of the wildfly server? It works like this with java.util.Date.

Comment: One thing to note is Yasson is not being used here, Jackson is. I changed my test to use similar parameters and it seemed to work for me. Do you by chance have some kind of reproducer?

Comment: My Customer entity was annotated with javax.xml.bind.annoation.XmlRootElement. If I remove this annotation from the Customer entity it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I Added this annotation to java.util.Date fields and this works;

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
private Date myDateField;
```

The pattern values should take all time units;